# Django regroup using group

Tags: django, templates, group-by

So I have this

|  Element  |  Brand  |
      A          1
      B          2
      C          2
      D          1

How do I do to group them so the brands doesnt repeat, I mean I dont want to show the brands twice, I want to render each brand once. 
NOTE : Brand is a foreign key

------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------

```
class Productos(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey("TiposOpciones", null=True, blank=True, related_name='Productos_tipo')
    marca = models.ManyToManyField(MarcasOpciones, related_name='Productos_marca')
```

I want to show the marca field only once, not repeat it. I tried this but it's repeating it:

```
                {% for sth in productos.all %}
                {% ifequal articulo.Tipos|slugify sth.tipo|slugify %}
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                            {% for sthelse in sth.marca.all %}

                                {{ sthelse }}

                            {% endfor %}
                    </a>
                </li>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
```

So how should I group it ?

Comment: Some template code could be useful. Or an expected output. Wanting to render each brand once means nothing to me. You can eventually take a look at django [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) tag

Comment: I've been the whole day trying but I couldnt make it work, would you give me a hand ?

Comment: Edit the question and show some example code. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ready, check out if you can do something I would really apreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think  you want to show all `marcas` related to some `articulo` it via `product.type`. For this scenario I think you don't need to make any grouping, you can just find all the `marcas` you are interested in. Here is what i mean:

```
#in the view
#add .distinct() if you get duplicates
marcas = MarcasOpciones.object.filter(Productos_marca__tipo=articulo.Tipos) 

#in the template
{% for sthelse in marcas %}
    <li><a href="#">{{ sthelse }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

There is one possible drawback with this approach - we are not using the `|slugify` tag to create the match. A possible solution to this is to create `slug` fields for the both models.

However, if that approach doesn't suit you. I advice you to move all the matching logic in the view and again send only the needed `marcas` in the template.

```
#in the view
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

marcas = []
for sth in productos.all():
    if slugify(articulo.Tipos) == slugify(sth.tipo):
        for sthelse in sth.marca.all():
            if sthelse not in marcas:
                marcas.append(sthelse)
                #if you need the product that match that marca
                #you can add it here
                #sthelse.product = sth
```

Comment: Rigth, but this is for a menu in which the admin can add more items, so I need it to be really flexible , I am not a django expert, but as I understand with the code you wrote up here its not flexible, I need to give a specific "marca" , I need to be really really flexible like the code I'm showing

Comment: I'm sorry I still can't understand what's the issue.

Comment: (I'm a beginner on Django) You mean that the code you wrote on the view , is exactly the same code I wrote on the template ? How can I include it on the template ?

Comment: Also I believe that code will still repeat both marcas, the append doesnt join them , it duplicates them